# What data entered into postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

This is a web application which uses Postgres to store data pushed from various modules of the web application.

From Postgres side, how can I know what data entered/modified into Postgres? I mean if there is any Postgres data logging?

Postgres has 4-5 schemas & each schema has 2-3 tables. Each table has 10-20 records.

EDIT (8 Sept 2021):

1. `log_destination=csvlog` - I tried different destinations to see if I'm getting the required logs. But all log destination are capturing the same logs.

2: `reload` - Did restarted server every time I made
changes to `postgresql.conf`.
3: The logs are being generated at
`/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_log` directory with format
`postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log`. Where latest logs are generated, but as mentioned in comment, I'm not getting all the query logs that are being executed on Postgres by the web application

4: I installed Postgres 9.6 as a Docker container.

5: I'm making changes in
`/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` which is reflected in
database query `SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name LIKE '%log%';` after restart.

EDIT (7 Sept 2021):

```
name                       |setting                       |
---------------------------+------------------------------+
log_autovacuum_min_duration|-1                            |
log_checkpoints            |off                           |
log_connections            |off                           |
log_destination            |csvlog                        |
log_directory              |pg_log                        |
log_disconnections         |off                           |
log_duration               |off                           |
log_error_verbosity        |default                       |
log_executor_stats         |off                           |
log_file_mode              |0600                          |
log_filename               |postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log|
log_hostname               |off                           |
log_line_prefix            |                              |
log_lock_waits             |off                           |
log_min_duration_statement |-1                            |
log_min_error_statement    |error                         |
log_min_messages           |warning                       |
log_parser_stats           |off                           |
log_planner_stats          |off                           |
log_replication_commands   |off                           |
log_rotation_age           |1440                          |
log_rotation_size          |10240                         |
log_statement              |all                           |
log_statement_stats        |off                           |
log_temp_files             |-1                            |
log_timezone               |Etc/UTC                       |
log_truncate_on_rotation   |off                           |
logging_collector          |on                            |
syslog_facility            |local0                        |
syslog_ident               |postgres                      |
syslog_sequence_numbers    |on                            |
syslog_split_messages      |on                            |
wal_log_hints              |off                           |
```

EDIT

Comment: why don't you keep created_at, modified_at columns and when that modules saving the data in postgres will update the modified_at column if modified and created_at column will be set if data is created(this is for one time for a row).

Comment: This is an existing application and we're trying to fix a bug. If I want to add created_at, and modified_at, then I've to do several changes at application level, which might not be easy.

Comment: My Postgres version is `PostgreSQL 9.6.22 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Debian 9.6.22-1.pgdg90+1), compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit|`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for highlighting. I've updated the `tag` in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Check a the logging configuration in `postgresql.conf`. You want to set up this [What to log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT) in particular `log_statement`. For your use the `mod` setting would be appropriate. Then you can look at the Postgres log to see what was changed and when. You might also want to set `log_connections` and `log_disconnections` to see what user the connection is running as.

Comment: I've tried doing these settings in `postgresql.conf` but I'm not getting log of all the queries that are being executed on the Postgres. There are many tables which gets updated (mainly INSERT) from web application inside Postgres, but those are not reflected into the log file. I've added my log settings in original post with EDIT as the character length of comments is not enough.

Comment: I've tried with `log_statement="all"` as well.

Comment: You have `log_destination  csvlog ` set which will log to a CSV file, is that what you want? Did you `reload` the server after making the changes to make then take effect? If you did reload and are not seeing queries then you are looking in the wrong Postgres log. How did you install Postgres? Where are you making the changes in `postgresql.conf`? Add the answers to as update to your question.

Comment: Updated answers to your question in OP under `EDIT (8 Sept 2021):`

Comment: I would turn on `log_connections/log_disconnections`. If you are not seeing any connections or queries from the Web app then you are looking at the wrong log file. It is not clear to me whether the log file you are looking at is in the host or the Docker container?

Comment: I'll try enabling `log_connections/log_disconnections`. However, its worth noting that I'm getting the log of "some" queries that are executed by the web application, but not "all". Also, I can see log file being generated with time stamp & this same log file get updates for that "some" log. The problem I'm facing is why all queries are not getting logged? The log file is in the Docker container. I don't think it will be in host is I'm running Postgres as a Docker container.

Comment: What queries are being logged and what are not?